# Vuejs infinite loop

Tags: laravel, vue.js

here my code, and the vue warn:
menu.js:39016 [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
i dont know why, pls help me. I have this when i use v-for to the loop

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Additional Information</th>
                <th scope="col">Created By</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="menu in menuData" :key="menu.id">
                <th scope="row">{{ stt++ }}</th>
                <td>{{ menu.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ menu.image_url }}</td>
                <td><ul v-for="category in menu.categories" :key="category.id"><li>{{ category.name }}</li></ul></td>
                <td>{{ menu.additional_information }}</td>
                <td>{{ menu.menu_user.name }}</td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            },
            data: function() {
                return {
                    stt: 0,
                    menuData: [],
                }
            },
            created: function() {
                axios.get('/api/menus').then((response) => {
                    this.menuData = response.data.data.data;
                    console.log(this.menuData);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are changing your data directly in the `template` causing a rerender.

```html
<th scope="row">{{ stt++ }}</th>
```

Do not mutate data in the template.

As @rjcarl mentioned You can get the row index in the `v-for`

```html
<tr v-for="(menu, index) in menuData" :key="menu.id">
<th scope="row">{{ index }}</th>
```

Comment: Use the `index` or the data's `id` instead to display the row index. `(menu, index) in menuData`